# Lua script for World of Warcraft: Get Quest Info

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft-modding

I'm looking to make a very simple addon or even a macro where I can enter a quest ID and get the quest completion status.  As it is, I know I can use `IsQuestFlaggedCompleted` to get the quest status, but I wanted to also get the name of the quest so the return in the chat log will show something a little more understandable.
For example:
Enter `/questDone 43502`
instead of just `43502: true` as the output, I want it to look like `A Change of Seasons: Quest Completed`.

I see a function `C_TaskQuest.GetQuestInfoByQuestID` that's supposed to return the quest's title, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.  It always seems to return `nil` for the quest name...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following which creates a tooltip and scans the name:

```
local MyScanningTooltip = CreateFrame("GameTooltip", "MyScanningTooltip", UIParent, "GameTooltipTemplate")

local QuestTitleFromID = setmetatable({}, { __index = function(t, id)
    MyScanningTooltip:SetOwner(UIParent, "ANCHOR_NONE")
    MyScanningTooltip:SetHyperlink("quest:"..id)
    local title = MyScanningTooltip.TextLeft1:GetText()
    MyScanningTooltip:Hide()
    if title and title ~= RETRIEVING_DATA then
        t[id] = title
        return title
    end
end })
```

Then use this table like this:

```
print(QuestTitleFromID[43502])
```

Comment: This absolutely doesn't answers the question. The OP looking for any quest-completition addon/macro - with specific usage, `/questDone id1` or like. You just brutally copied some source code from the [wowinterface](https://www.wowinterface.com/forums/showthread.php?t=46934) and even doesn't citing the source. This is a bad manner...